# why i can't run my node js file using npm package in hyper terminal

Tags: node.js, npm-package, hyperterminal

Cannot find module 'C:\Users\wp\node-intro\node_modules\car-names\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:438:19)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:680:18)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\wp\node-intro\index.js:3:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: 'C:\Users\wp\node-intro\node_modules\car-names\package.json',
requestPath: 'car-names'
}

Node.js v18.16.1

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from same issue when I created file Schemas. So I just moved the file in main folder so u have to move your folder to the main file in which all the files are saved while creating your project. "In your case  I think Your file is moved into Module._compile do check and move that into wp " I think it will help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).